# Dont’t change active Button while I’m listing a category?

Tags: links, buttons

I have a simple Navigation: *Blog, About, Contact*. Mainsite is *Blog*. To keep the current Button highlighted, I used this in my CSS:

```
    li.current_page_item a{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #212121;
    padding-bottom: 1px; 
}
```

It works pretty fine. But I want to keep *Blog* still active while I’m listing an item from my categories. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I guess you're willig to keep the button `home` active also on the category archive page.

Comment: Yes, but how can I do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I did it this way::

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
     if(is_category() && $item->title == "Blog"){ //Notice you can change the conditional from is_single() and $item->title
             $classes[] = "special-class";
     }
     return $classes;
}
```